# Symfony2 form_widget on select option

Tags: symfony

I need to give a value to my select, but i don't find how add a attr selected to my option.

i would like something like that :

```
{{ form_widget(form.zone,{ 'option' : {'selected' : 7 }}) }}
```

for selected my option with the value '7', its possible ?

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Instead of 'option', you should just give the widget a 'value'.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer.
I have already try this, my select had this value, but option with this value is not selected.

```
<select id="zone" value="7">
<option value="0">International</option>
<option value="7">Oceanie</option>
<option value="1">Union Europeenne</option>
...
```

and for this work i think i need :

```
<option selected='selected' value="7">Oceanie</option>
```

Comment: Try with this:
{{ form_widget(form.zone, { value: '7' }) }}

Comment: Thanks that work, i have try firstly the same without the quote, thats why that doesnt work...
Now i try to give a variable and i have again a fail.

I try {{ form_widget(form.zone,{ 'value' :  extensionitem.zone.numZone  }) }} or {{ form_widget(form.zone,{ 'value' :  'extensionitem.zone.numZone'  }) }} but doesnt work :/

Comment: In this case, try with twig extension trim, like this:
{{ form_widget(form.zone, { value: extensionitem.zone.numZone|trim }) }}

Comment: Thanks you all is ok ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.zone,{ 'attr' : {'value' : 7 }}) }}
```